# In Tableau how can I create a calculated field that categorizes data based on data across rows?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau table that looks like this :

[image: Initial_Dataset]

I want the following output:

[image: Desired_Output]

Comment: Read about conditional sets and LOD calcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If don't mind only having the 'Part' pill on the view, like this...

[Example of where to place your pills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arjz4.png)

Then the calculation below will meet your needs. Removing 'Types' from the view allows the data to aggregate in a way we can use to come up with the categories you want.

[Size Category Calculation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Yep.png)

However, if you would like to add more dimensions to the view we need to control the level of detail in our calculation. Thankfully, we can do this with LOD functions.

[image: Level of detail calculation]

This calculation "fixes" out Level of Detail at the Part LOD. You can see I have added 'Another Dim' the view and it still works.

Comment: Hey, this is the most simple and elegant solution I've seen for this issue. This was my first time using the MIN/MAX functions for a string. However, the only catch is that I cannot put any other dimensions in the view. Adding measures doesn't do anything, but adding another dimension after part messes this up. Why is this happening? Any ways to avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to associate the Type with integer values E.g small =1 , medium = 3, Large = 5. Call this field TypeInt

Create a calculated field Type_Calc =  {Fixed [Part]:SUM(TypeInt)}

If Type_Calc = 1 Then Category = "Small"
elseif Type_Calc = 4 Then Catgory = "Small_Medium"....

and so on.

Assumption is that the same Type is not repeated within the Part.